# Conditional probability of exponential random variable

Tags: probability

This question comes directly from a chapter in Gut's "Intermediate Probability" that focuses on conditional probability. I'm using this problem as more practice solving conditional probability questions.

The life $T$ (hours) of the bulb in an overhead project follows an exponential($10$)-distribution. During a normal week, it is used a Poisson($12$)-distributed number of lectures lasting exactly one hour each. Find the probability that a projector with a newly installed bulb functions throughout a normal week (without replacing the bulb).

The answer is given as $\exp \{-12(1-e^{-1/10})\} $, but I'm unsure how to arrive at it. My attempt was:

Let $T$ represent the lifetime of the bulb, and let $N$ represent the number of lectures given in a week.

$$\mathbb{P}(T > n | N=n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigg \{ \int_{t=n}^\infty f_T(t) f_N(n) dt \Bigg \} $$
but this doesn't get me much, and I'm not even sure if I could solve the above equation.

I would appreciate any hints or suggestions for how to arrive at the given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that if the bulb lasts for an hour on a given day that it is used, then it survives to the next time it is used, *and* each time it is used, it behaves as if it were new, because its lifetime is exponentially distributed.  So we first need to calculate the probability of this survival:  this is simply $$p = \Pr[T > 1] = e^{-1/10}.$$  Now, if $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 12)$ is the random number of times it is used in a week, $X \mid N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N,1-p)$ counts the number of lectures that the bulb fails in a week.  We want the marginal (unconditional) probability $\Pr[X = 0]$.  To this end, we note $$\Pr[X = k] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr[X = k \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n]$$ by the law of total probability.  The conditional probability is binomial, and the second is Poisson, so $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = 0] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n}{0} (1-p)^0 p^n e^{-12} \frac{12^n}{n!} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-12} \frac{(12p)^n}{n!} \\ &= e^{12p} e^{-12} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-12p} \frac{(12p)^n}{n!} \\ &= e^{-12(1-p)} = e^{-12(1-e^{-1/10})}, \end{align*}$$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the probability that the life time $T$ of the bulb is more than the number of hours spent on lectures (which is equal to $N$, since each lecture is one hour), e.g. you need to find
$$P(T>N).$$
Here's one approach. If $N=n$ for some integer $n\geq 0$, then you also need $T>n$. I can thus rewrite the above probability as
$$P(T>N) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(T>n,N=n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(T>n|N=n)P(N=n),$$
where the last equality uses the definition of conditional probability. There is another argument for this equality, but I don't know if you have covered it yet. I include it later in the post.

Continuing with the last sum, you know that $T$ and $N$ are independent, so $P(T>n|N=n) = P(T>n)$, which you know, since $T$ has an exponential distribution, and since $N$ is Poission, you also know the value of $P(N=n)$. Plugging it in, you get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T>n|N=n)P(N=n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(T>n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{10}n}e^{-12}\frac{12^n}{n!}$$
$$=e^{-12}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-\frac{1}{10}}12)^n}{n!}.$$

Recall that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is true for any $x$, and thus the above expression can be rewritten as
$$e^{-12}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-\frac{1}{10}}12)^n}{n!} = e^{-12}e^{12\exp{(-1/10)}}=e^{-12(1-\exp(-1/10))},$$
which is what you are looking for.

Now, concerning my very first equality, you could also use the law of iterated expectations to conclude that
$$P(T>N) = \mathbb{E}[P(T>N|N)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(T>n|N=n)P(N=n).$$