# How to find probability a projector with newly installed lightbulb will last over 4 successive work weeks

Tags: probability

The set up is similar to a problem previously solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299832/conditional-probability-of-exponential-random-variable) from Gut's "Intermediate Probability". As such the finding the probability the projector lasts a full week was easy, but I am having trouble understanding what is meant in a later part of the problem and would like help understanding how to approach the problem. That said I shall include the full problem set up for clarity.

*The random lifetime $T$ (hour) of the light bulb in an overhead projector follows exponential distribution with mean = $M$ hours. During a normal work week the projector is used for a random number $N$ of lectures lasting one hour. N has a Poisson distribution with mean $=K$*. After finding $p(M,K)$, the probability that a projector with a new bulb will last a full work week (which as stated was already covered so no help needed there), we are asked the following and I am lost:

*1) Consider that $M$ is imposed by the commercial brand, indicate how to compute $g(M)$ such that $K\leq g(M)$ will force $P(M,K) \geq 0.95$*.
*2) Restrictions are imposed on lecture scheduling such that $K=g(M)$. Compute probability a projector with a new bulb will last 4 work weeks*.

I believe from Gut's notation $g(M)$ is the probability generating function but I don't understand how to progress with this problem. My guess for part 2 is that $p(M,K) = 0.95$ and we just need to extend lasting a week to lasting 4 weeks with this. But I do not know where to begin with 1.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is not the probability generating function; the question is asking you to find a function $g$ such that $p(M,K) \ge 0.95$ when $K \le g(M)$.

You showed that $p(M, K) = e^{-K(1-e^{-1/M})}$. The condition $p(M, K) \ge 0.95$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
e^{-K(1-e^{-1/M})} &\ge 0.95
\\
K(1-e^{-1/M}) &\le -\log0.95
\\
K & \le - \frac{\log 0.95}{1-e^{-1/M}}.
\end{align}
So the right-hand side is how you should define $g(M)$.